# Kile '[PDFLaTeX] failed to start' when using TeX Live 2013 + self compiled Kile

Tags: 13.04, latex, kile

On Ubuntu 13.04 I installed Tex Live 2013 and then compiled Kile from source (in order to avoid the large amount of dependencies that come with Ubuntu's version of Kile). Kile runs, but when I tried to compile a .tex file using PDFLaTeX I got the following error message:

```
[PDFLaTeX] failed to start
```

How do I make Kile find PDFLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need to run Kile once as root. In a terminal enter:

```
sudo kile
```

Let Kile start, then close it and run Kile as normal. You should now be able to compile!